# Python Unknown pattern finding

Tags: python, find, design-patterns

Okay, basically what I want is to compress a file by reusing code and then at runtime replace missing code. What I've come up with is really ugly and slow, at least it works. The problem is that the file has no specific structure, for example 'aGVsbG8=\n', as you can see it's base64 encoding. My function is really slow because the length of the file is 1700+ and it checks for patterns 1 character at the  time. Please help me with new better code or at least help me with optimizing what I got :). Anything that helps is welcome! BTW i have already tried compression libraries but they didn't compress as good as my ugly function.

```
def c_long(inp, cap=False, b=5):
    import re,string
    if cap is False: cap = len(inp)
    es = re.escape; le=len; ref = re.findall; ran = range; fi = string.find
    c = b;inpc = inp;pattern = inpc[:b]; l=[]
    rep = string.replace; ins = list.insert
    while True:
        if c == le(inpc) and le(inpc) > b+1: c = b; inpc = inpc[1:]; pattern = inpc[:b]
        elif le(inpc) <= b: break
        if c == cap: c = b; inpc = inpc[1:]; pattern = inpc[:b]
        p = ref(es(pattern),inp)
        pattern += inpc[c]
        if le(p) > 1 and le(pattern) >= b+1:
            if l == []: l = [[pattern,le(p)+le(pattern)]]
            elif le(ref(es(inpc[:c+2]),inp))+le(inpc[:c+2]) < le(p)+le(pattern):
                x = [pattern,le(p)+le(inpc[:c+1])]
                for i in ran(le(l)):
                    if x[1] >= l[i][1] and x[0][:-1] not in l[i][0]: ins(l,i,x); break
                    elif x[1] >= l[i][1] and x[0][:-1] in l[i][0]: l[i] = x; break
                inpc = inpc[:fi(inpc,x[0])] + inpc[le(x[0]):]
                pattern = inpc[:b]
                c = b-1
        c += 1
    d = {}; c = 0
    s = ran(le(l))
    for x in l: inp = rep(inp,x[0],'{%d}' % s[c]); d[str(s[c])] = x[0]; c += 1
    return [inp,d]

def decompress(inp,l): return apply(inp.format, [l[str(x)] for x in sorted([int(x) for x in l.keys()])])
```

Comment: I did a few experiments with different kinds of strings (randomly generated, with repetitive patterns, with few occuring characters, with many occuring characters), and I couldn't find any string which your function compresses as good as `bz2` or `zlib` -- it's not even close.  Moreover, your function fails for many strings, like `"abcdefgabcdefg"`.  Unfortunately, your code is almost unreadable, so I won't take the time to debug it.

Comment: @user795085 - No offense intended, but this could win a code obsfucation contest... Please don't do things like `le=len`, `ran=range`, `fi=string.find` etc! It's evil, it _really_ makes the code hard to read and it only saves you a whopping 2 characters...  Verbosity (in moderation) is a very good thing!  (That having been said, I'm guilty of continually doing `import numpy as np`, which confuses many people, but it's the de-facto community standard. `le=len` is just downright evil...)

Comment: @Joe: `le=len` is a micro-optimisation.  It pulls `len` in the local namespace under the name `le`, and look-ups in the local namespace are faster.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: speed optimisation but legibility obfuscation. `for i in ran(le(l)):` is not only evil obfuscation but silly -- it is likely to run faster with `xrange()` (instead of `range()`), or with `enumerate()`. There are other slowdown-sillinesses and/or archaisms like using `string.find()` and `apply()`.

Comment: @John: I just wanted to point out the idea of `le = len`.  I did not mean to say it's a good idea, as should be clear from my answer.

Comment: your code is hurting my eyes. Please, avoid using `;`. Break the lines! `le=len` isn't optimisation. `len=len` is!

Comment: @JBernardo: `le = len` is premature optimisation. `len = len` is broken Python code that doesn't even run inside of a function.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to compress base64-encoded data is to first convert it to binary data -- this will already save 25 percent of the storage space:

```
>>> s = "YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXo=\n"
>>> t = s.decode("base64")
>>> len(s)
37
>>> len(t)
26
```

In most cases, you can compress the string even further using some compression algorithm, like `t.encode("bz2")` or `t.encode("zlib")`.

A few remarks on your code:  There are lots of factors that make the code hard to read: inconsistent spacing, overly long lines, meaningless variable names, unidiomatic code, etc.  An example: Your `decompress()` function could be equivalently written as

```
def decompress(compressed_string, substitutions):
    subst_list = [substitutions[k] for k in sorted(substitutions, key=int)]
    return compressed_string.format(*subst_list)
```

Now it's already much more obvious what it does.  You could go one step further:  Why is `substitutions` a dictionary with the string keys `"0"`, `"1"` etc.?  Not only is it strange to use strings instead of integers -- you don't need the keys at all!  A simple list will do, and `decompress()` will simplify to

```
def decompress(compressed_string, substitutions):
    return compressed_string.format(*substitutions)
```

You might think all this is secondary, but if you make the rest of your code equally readable, you will find the bugs in your code yourself.  (There *are* bugs -- it crashes for `"abcdefgabcdefg"` and many other strings.)

Answer (score 1):

Typically one would pump the program through a compression algorithm optimized for text, then run that through `exec`, e.g.

```
code="""..."""
exec(somelib.decompress(code), globals=???, locals=???)
```

It may be the case that `.pyc`/`.pyo` files are compressed already, and one could check by creating one with `x="""aaaaaaaa"""`, then increasing the length to `x="""aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaa"""` and seeing if the size changes appreciably.